Power series of matrices that is similar to hyperbolic sine
Consider a power series
$$
\phi = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(M_2M_1)^kM_2}{(2k+1)!}
$$
where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are symmetric positive semidefinite matrices, thus standard square roots $M_1^{\frac{1}{2}}$, $M_2^{\frac{1}{2}}$, $(M_1M_2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, $(M_2M_1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ exist. I'm trying to obtain an analytical expression of $\phi$. I attempted to connect this power series with the Taylor expansion of the $\sinh$ function, having $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{((M_2M_1)^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2k+1}(M_2M_1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}M_2}{(2k+1)!},$$ but $(M_2M_1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ may be singular.
In another attempt to solve $$\psi = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(M_1M_2)^k}{(2k)!},$$ I already have $$\psi = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{((M_1M_2)^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\cosh((M_1M_2)^{\frac{1}{2}}).$$ I hope this will be helpful.
By the way, my question is a part of solving $e^{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & M_2\\
M_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}}$, if there is any other approach, please let me know.
Edit:
I will present some of my findings without providing proofs. A particular scenario arises when $M_1$ is positive definite (PD), in which case we have:$$\phi=M_1^{-1}\sqrt{M_1M_2}\sinh(\sqrt{M_1M_2}).$$ In the more general case, when $M_1 \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $M_2 \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ share the same rank $N-k$, we can transform them to have PD principal submatrices $\tilde{M}_1 \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{N-k})$ and $\tilde{M}_2 \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{N-k})$ through an orthogonal basis change. Consequently, we obtain: $$\tilde{\phi}:=\tilde{M}_1^{-1}\sqrt{\tilde{M}_1\tilde{M}_3}\sinh(\sqrt{\tilde{M}_1\tilde{M}_2}),$$ and $$\phi = f \circ \tilde{\phi},$$ where $f: \mathbb{R}^{N-k} \to \mathbb{R}^N$ is a linear map.

I guess you have already found out that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & M_2 \\ M_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{2k} = \begin{bmatrix} (M_2M_1)^k & 0 \\ 0 & (M_1M_2)^k \end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, given that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(2k)!} = \cosh\sqrt{x} \quad\quad\&\quad\quad 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(2k+1)!} = \frac{\sinh\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}},
$$
one has :
$$
\begin{align}
\exp \begin{bmatrix} 0 & M_2 \\ M_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
   &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\{ \frac{1}{(2k)!} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & M_2 \\ M_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{2k} + \frac{1}{(2k+1)!} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & M_2 \\ M_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{2k+1} \right\} \\
   &= \begin{bmatrix} \cosh\sqrt{M_2M_1} & 0 \\ 0 & \cosh\sqrt{M_1M_2} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & M_2 \\ M_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sinh\sqrt{M_2M_1}}{\sqrt{M_2M_1}} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{\sinh\sqrt{M_1M_2}}{\sqrt{M_1M_2}} \end{bmatrix} \\
   &= \begin{bmatrix} \cosh\sqrt{M_2M_1} & M_2\frac{\sinh\sqrt{M_1M_2}}{\sqrt{M_1M_2}} \\ M_1\frac{\sinh\sqrt{M_2M_1}}{\sqrt{M_2M_1}} & \cosh\sqrt{M_1M_2} \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
And you are basically done, at least analytically.
As you recalled, since $M_1$ and $M_2$ are positive semidefinite, their products are also positive semidefinite and the expressions $\sqrt{M_1M_2}$ and $\sqrt{M_1M_2}$ are well defined. However, they may be singular, but the quantity $\frac{\sinh\sqrt{M_1M_2}}{\sqrt{M_1M_2}}$ has to be understood as a formal/symbolic expression only, which is translated through the following expansion :
$$
\frac{\sinh A}{A} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{(2n+1)!}
$$
It doesn't contain any negative powers of $A$, so that this expression is correctly defined, even for singular matrices. In a component-wise / eigenvalue point of view, if you diagonlized a singular $A$, the component associated to the zero eigenvalue would become $\lim_{\lambda\to0} \frac{\sinh{\lambda}}{\lambda} = 1$.

Thank you for your response. You are correct in providing the expression for the matrix exponential. I managed to derive a closed-form solution for some specific $M_1$, and I am hoping to obtain a sufficiently accurate closed-form solution in this more general scenario. This will help me to handle the integral involving such a matrix exponential (matrix Ricatti equation). However, I suspect that there might not be a closed-form solution for this general case. As a next step, I plan to explore the diagonal $M_1$ case.
